# Opencart Website Down Page

Tags: mysql, opencart

Just wondering if there is an easy way in opencart to display a page saying the website is down if the MySql database is unavailable rather than displaying all the errors?

Currently my host is having problems with there MySQL servers and when I go to my site I get a bunch of errors:

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in xxxxxxxxx/public_html/system/database/mysql.php on line 6

Notice: Error: Could not make a database link using xxxxxxxxxx@localhost in /home/flamingl/public_html/system/database/mysql.php on line 7

Comment: Yes, it is possible. There is a hook in the `index.php` that is checking whether the *maintenance mode* is turned on or not. In Your `index.php` You should put check whether the connection to DB was successful and if not You should immediately switch to maintenance mode manually. You can do this by including the maintenance mode template and exiting the runtime. But I recommend this solution only on production environment, on Your local You should be wise of any error that may occur.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a nice way to do this in OpenCart. That said, here's the dirty way:

Create a `maintenance.php` in your root directory with the following inside it (this will be loaded if the database connection fails):

```
<?php
// Tell any crawlers visiting the site that it's currently unavailable
header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
header('Retry-After: 300');//300 seconds
?>
<html><body>
<h1>Sorry, the website is currently unavailable</h1>
...
...
</body></html>
```

Edit the `__construct` method in `/system/database/mysql.php` to be:

```
public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
  if (!$this->link = @mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)) {
    exit(include(DIR_SYSTEM . '../maintenance.php'));
  }

  if (!mysql_select_db($database, $this->link)) {
    exit(include(DIR_SYSTEM . '../maintenance.php'));
  }

  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $this->link);
  mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $this->link);
  mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION=utf8", $this->link);
  mysql_query("SET SQL_MODE = ''", $this->link);
}
```